# Does the interface PBX phones plug into limit modem speed?

Tags: modem, telephony

Many hotel etc phones plug into a digital PBX, often with a non-standard interface. Does the interface PBX phones plug into limit modem speed to below 56k?

Comment: What’s a PBX? Care to add a little more context?

Comment: @user3840170 - PBX = Private Branch eXchange. A telephone exchange used by businesses (like hotels) for internal calls as well as calling in or out. It gives options like "dial 100 for reception" and "dail a 9 to get an outside line".

Comment: The point is, I’d rather have it explained in the question body. That, and how the presence of a PBX is supposed to interact with modem speed. As is, it is rather laconic.

Comment: This is highly dependent on the type of PBX and the type of phone (and thus the type of interface for that phone on the PBX). In many cases I suspect you just won't be able to connect a modem at all.

Comment: I am assuming that there is a data port on the phones themselves that works with a modem.

Answer (score 8):

In "modern" analog telephone systems (as in since ca. 1990), only the final bit of the network from the exchange to the telephone / modem is analog; everything after the first exchange is digital.

V.90/V.92 ("56k") works if that first digital exchange supports it. So if that PBX supports V.90, 56k works. If it doesn't, it doesn't.

Comment: I suspect  that you today also can't be sure if the local PBX is connected to a "true" landline, if it is VOIP on fiber or if it is VOIP on mobile connection. The second two will probably mean the signal will be digitized a second time.

Comment: I am talking about a digital PBX connected to a digital T1 line like in the 1990s. I am particularly worried about the nonstandard interfaces many PBX vendors used.

Comment: @YuhongBao T1 means you're talking about the US and Canada? And what do you mean by non-standard interface? (I'm from Germany: The PBX I'm thinking about would have analog or ISDN S0 on one end, and an ISDN primary multiplex (30 channels at 64kBit each) on the other. Most of these, at least from the mid/late 90s onward, would support V.90.)

Comment: Yes, US and Canada. I know ISDN was common in Germany.

Comment: Huh? Since when does the PBX have a say in 56k connections? 56k is based on use of T1/ISDN connection and a single D/A converter at customer site.

Comment: @Raffzahn My understanding was that that single D/A is part of the PBX, because upstream of the PBX, everything is digital, and downstream, there are analog phones? But my memory might be getting rusty, and / or things might get lost in translation.

Comment: @MichaelGraf Exactly.The important part is that this DAC is clocked by the network signal, not the PBM, thus it can be assumed as transparent. Also, the DAC may as well be within the terminal, depending on PBX type.

Comment: In this case, many phones have an analog data port for example.

Comment: @Raffzahn I seem to recall that the PBX in the place where I worked in 1996/1997 needed modem lines to be configured as such -- perhaps turn off a low pass filter?

Comment: @MichaelGraf Quite possible, there were PBX with additional filters which could have reduced upstream data rate. Some even digital ones. These could be especially problematic with 14.4 .. 33.6 kBit class devices, thus 56k upstream as well.

Comment: If e.g. a PBX used a 12-bit DAC and ADC operating at a sample rate of 16kHz, I wouldn't think the fact that the PBX was "digital" but didn't explicitly recognize 56k communication would necessarily be a problem.  As to whether any PBX hardware would do things that way, I have no idea, but using higher sample rate and sample depth in the digital parts of the PBX would make the analog parts of the PBX simpler and easier to design, and the total bandwidth of all the signals the PBX would have to deal with even when using a 16kHz sample rate would be low enough as to not be a problem.

Answer (score 4):

> Many hotel etc phones plug into a digital PBX, often with a non-standard interface.

I'm not really sure what 'non standard interface' means in this case. The interface of any terminal line is either digital or analogue. If digital it might be almost always an ISDN variant.

A definite answer can only be made with detailed information about how that interface is supposed to be 'different'.

> Does the interface PBX phones plug into limit modem speed to below 56k?

No. At least not without being really unusual. Especially not the plug itself.

---

56k speed, commonly by V.90/V.92 (*1), is only available downstream and relies on having only a single DAC on receiver side. This is done by the host (ISP) side connecting direct to the digital channel creating a native [PCM signal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-code_modulation) using the full (*2) digital bandwidth. On subscriber side this signal is put thru an DAC either on the PBX side (in case of analogue terminals) or within the terminal (*3). The later is often the case if the phone provides a dedicated (analogue) modem plug.

It should always work independent of PBX and terminal, as workings are dictated by the transmission clock rate. Any fiddling with the clock rate by the PBX would break voice communication as well - or at least distort it past usefulness.

Of course, PBX and/or terminal may involve less than good line quality and massive line filters restricting the analogue signal, thus hampering the modems ability to decode the signal in useful manner.

Upstream on 56k Modems is BTW always 'only' 33.6 kBit, as the modem is of course not able to inject a digital stream. Still, V.92 offers an almost digital mode of 48 kBit upstream at cost of reducing downstream to 33.6 kBit to avoid interference.

---

*1 - X2 (USR) and Flex56 (Rockwell) were other early system, but soon replaced by V.90 and V.92

*2 - Well, 85% in case of European 64 kBit lines

*3 - Vulgo the phone :))

Comment: It's definitely very possible to break data communication without noticeably impacting voice. A VoIP segment over a jittery network before we get to the ISDN and any chance of getting a good quality fax through without reencoding in a latency-tolerant form (the protocol for which escapes me right now -- it was 15 years ago I worked with any of this) is gone.